# Properly closing connection and checking for connection leaks

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection

I have three problems for which I am not finding a solution. We are using connection pool in our project. We see in our project the statements are closed after the connection is closed. I know that in case of a connection pool, after a connection is closed the physical connection to the database is not closed but returns to the pool for reuse. So my questions are:

1. What will happen if statements are closed after a connection is closed? Will the statements be closed properly/will closing the connection close all the statements and closing the statements are redundant/the statements are open and though the connection returns to the pool, it is not reusable because of open statements? (We are using both Statement and PreparedStatement).
2. Can I use the same Statement/PreparedStatement object for multiple queries? I know we can reuse the same PreparedStatement for executing the same query mane times with multiple inputs, but my question is can I use it for executing two different queries at different points in time? Like:

   ```
   PreparedStatement pstme = null;
   // Do Stuff
   pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
   //Do Stuff
   pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
   //Do stuff
   pstmt.close();
   con.close();
   ```
3. If there any way to check for connection leaks in application and avoid them, instead of going through each line of code?

Comment: You're asking three different questions, although they are related, that is too broad. Please rephrase your question to focus on a single aspect, and then - if necessary - post follow up questions.

Comment: Your second question shows you don't understand the difference between objects and variables. That code doesn't reuse a statement, it creates two distinct prepared statement instances, and leaks one. You are only reusing the variable, not the objects.

Comment: Below two osts created for the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49316446/proper-way-to-close-connection

Comment: I suggest you read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: I know about try with resources in Java 7, but the problem is our code base is huge and does not use try with resources. This was because it was earlier written using Java 6 and later made compatible with Java 7. So it is not possible to change in every place where a database resource is instantiated. Any static code analyzer capable of detecting connection leaks would be very good for me.