# Proper way to close connection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, database-connection

We are using connection pool in our project. We see in our project the statements are closed after the connection is closed. I know that in case of a connection pool, after a connection is closed the physical connection to the database is not closed but returns to the pool for reuse. So my question is:

What will happen if statements are closed after a connection is closed? Will the statements be closed properly/will closing the connection close all the statements and closing the statements are redundant/the statements are open and though the connection returns to the pool, it is not reusable because of open statements? (We are using both Statement and PreparedStatement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What will happen if statements are closed after a connection is closed?

Nothing. They were already closed. This is documented.

> Will the statements be closed properly

Yes. This is documented.

> /will closing the connection close all the statements

Yes. This is documented.

> and closing the statements are redundant

Yes.

> the statements are open and though the connection returns to the pool, it is not reusable because of open statements? (We are using both Statement and PreparedStatement).

I cannot make head or tail of this. If the connection is closed, the `Statements` and `ResultSets` derived from it are also closed. This is documented. If the `Connection` isn't closed, the `Statements` and `ResultSets` aren't closed either, unless you close them.

You must organise your code so that you don't rely on `ResultSets` beyond the life of the `Statement`, and `Statement` beyond the life of the `Connection`. This is trivially easy.

Comment: This does assume a properly implemented connection pool which limits the lifetime of the statements to that of the logical connection. This is not always the case (either intentionally for performance or due to bugs).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It does assume no bugs/non-compliant JDBC drivers/acts of God/*force majeure*/incorrect phase of the moon, ...

Comment: True, but having seen enough broken or intentionally non-compliant connection pools, I think it is an important caveat.

Comment: Well, I found out the closing connection without closing its associated Statements/ResultSet closes the statements/resultsets but the server gives a warningstating "Closing associated Statement, please do your own housekeeping". But we get connection leaks in our application. So we are unable to find out whether those connections will be reusable. Is there any way or any tool to find out connection leaks from Java applications? I am using Oracle 10g as DB.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I do not think any connection pool closes statements after a certain period of time. It only closes idle connections (not attached to any application) after a time specified by Idle Timeout at connection pool level.

Comment: @Anirban We weren't talking about closing after a certain period of time, but about what happens if the connection is closed. In any case, if the logical connection from a connection pool gets closed, its derived statements and result sets should get closed to. Regarding your other comment: asking for tools is explicitly off-topic. That said most static analyzers will warn you if you don't close connections, and some profilers can detect this in running code.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot. Now the open question is whether those connections will be reusable for future use?